# Javascript ondragend don't get the right coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am learning the html drag-and-drop methods. However, something is wrong when i want to make a div draggable, and change its position when i "drop" it.

I get the position of the cursor using e.screenX and e.screenY when I drag and drop it. However, I think that when I "drop" it, the coordinates changes comparing to the last coordinates when I was "dragging" it.

It works fine on Chrome and IE on PC running Windows 7; but the situation happens on both Safari and Chrome on my Mac, IE and Chrome on virtual machine running Windows 8.1. I am totally confused.

Thanks in advance. Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="drag-1" class="drag module" draggable="true">
        <div class="module-header">Draggable Div</div>
        <div class="module-content">
            <p>This is draggable.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    var draggable_div = document.getElementById("drag-1");
    var startPos = {};

    draggable_div.ondragstart = function(e){
//        e.dataTransfer.setData("_", "");
        console.log("start: " + e.offsetX + ", " + e.offsetY);
        startPos = {
            left: draggable_div.offsetLeft,
            top: draggable_div.offsetTop,
            offsetX: e.offsetX,
            offsetY: e.offsetY
        }
        console.log(  startPos );
    }

    draggable_div.ondrag = function(e){
//        console.log("drag.. " + e.offsetX + ", " + e.offsetY);
        draggable_div.style.top = startPos.top + e.offsetY - startPos.offsetY + "px";
        draggable_div.style.left = startPos.left + e.offsetX - startPos.offsetX + "px";
//        
    }

    draggable_div.ondragend = function(e){
//        console.log("drop: " + e.offsetX + ", " + e.offsetY);
        draggable_div.style.top = parseInt(startPos.top + e.offsetY - startPos.offsetY) + "px";
        draggable_div.style.left = parseInt(startPos.left + e.offsetX - startPos.offsetX) + "px";
//        console.log(  startPos );
    }


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```